# Loop through rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes: One has company name and date only. Other has only time stamps. Like shown below

```
    creationdate
0   2012-05-01 18:20:27.167000
1   2012-05-01 19:16:08.070000
2   2012-05-01 19:20:07.880000
3   2012-05-01 19:33:02.200000
4   2012-05-01 19:35:09.173000
5   2012-05-01 20:18:55.610000
6   2012-05-01 20:26:27.577000
7   2012-05-01 20:32:34.343000
8   2012-05-01 20:39:31.257000
9   2012-05-01 21:04:50.357000
10  2012-05-01 21:54:18.983000
11  2012-05-02 02:23:53.250000
12  2012-05-02 02:40:27.643000
13  2012-05-02 08:44:28.260000
```

And

```
   sitename        date
0    Google  2012-05-01
1    Google  2012-05-02
2    Google  2012-05-03
3    Google  2012-05-04
4    Google  2012-05-05
5    Google  2012-05-06
6    Google  2012-05-07
7    Google  2012-05-08
8    Google  2012-05-09
9    Google  2012-05-10
```

How can I efficiently loop through the second dataframe and extract the timestamp from the first dataframe corresponding to each date in the second dataframe.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? This looks like a really easy job for [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).

Comment: @Cyber : I set the date column of the second df as the index and tried looping through it while checking if the index was equal to the date extracted from each element of first dataframe. But this would check all the elements of the first dataframe everytime. That's y I was asking for an efficient way

Comment: @Cyber : Can you please tell your easy way? I am new to dataframes.

Comment: "loop through the **second dataframe**" and "extract the timestamp from the **second dataframe**" and "corresponding to each date in the **second dataframe**" - do you need **first dateframe** for something ?

Comment: @furas : Actually I have to calculate the average time difference between the timestamps given in the first dataframe  for a given date. And I want to do this for all the dates present in the second dataframe. For this I was trying to get the timestamps corresponding to one day and do the math

Comment: @furas : My mistake; loop through the second dataframe" and "extract the timestamp from the **first** dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merging (inner join) these two dataframes should work:

```
In [96]: df1['date'] = pd.DatetimeIndex (df1.creationdate).date

In [97]: df2['date'] = pd.DatetimeIndex (df2.date).date

In [98]: df=df1.merge(df2, on='date', how='inner')

In [99]: df
Out[99]: 
                 creationdate        date sitename
0  2012-05-01 18:20:27.167000  2012-05-01   Google
1  2012-05-01 19:16:08.070000  2012-05-01   Google
2  2012-05-01 19:20:07.880000  2012-05-01   Google
3  2012-05-01 19:33:02.200000  2012-05-01   Google
4  2012-05-01 19:35:09.173000  2012-05-01   Google
5  2012-05-01 20:18:55.610000  2012-05-01   Google
6  2012-05-01 20:26:27.577000  2012-05-01   Google
7  2012-05-01 20:32:34.343000  2012-05-01   Google
8  2012-05-01 20:39:31.257000  2012-05-01   Google
9  2012-05-01 21:04:50.357000  2012-05-01   Google
10 2012-05-01 21:54:18.983000  2012-05-01   Google
11 2012-05-02 02:23:53.250000  2012-05-02   Google
12 2012-05-02 02:40:27.643000  2012-05-02   Google
13 2012-05-02 08:44:28.260000  2012-05-02   Google
```

And then you can do analysis on `df` like

```
In [100]: df['time_diff'] = df.creationdate.diff()

In [101]: df.time_diff
Out[101]: 
0                NaT
1    00:55:40.903000
2    00:03:59.810000
3    00:12:54.320000
4    00:02:06.973000
5    00:43:46.437000
6    00:07:31.967000
7    00:06:06.766000
8    00:06:56.914000
9    00:25:19.100000
10   00:49:28.626000
11   04:29:34.267000
12   00:16:34.393000
13   06:04:00.617000
Name: time_diff, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Of course, your `creationdate` needs to be `datetime64[ns]` NOT STRING. Or you need to convert `pd.DatetimeIndex (df.creationdate)`